# EF 6 Not mapped attribute to count related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to have a new attribute, where to count the related registration entities. So I have defined a not mapped attribute to get the free seats.

```
public class Offer
{
    public int OfferID { get; set;}

    public int maxRegistration { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Registration> Registrations { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int FreeSeats
    {
        get
        {
            int registrationCounts = Registrations.Count();
            return maxRegistration - registrationCounts;
        }
    }
}
```

This bring me the error:

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first
```

So, i rewrite to code to:

```
MyApp.Context db = new MyApp.Context();  
int registrationCounts = db.Registration.Where(r => r.OfferID == OfferID).Count();
```

This works correctly, but it is very slow.
Is there an more elegant method to count the related entities of a dataset?

Comment: Why cant you directly use `Offer.Registrations.Count()` instead of creating a not mapped property.

Comment: Because I need the FreeSeats in different places, and will do the calculation in a central place. MVC Pattern.